# Create json on page load

Tags: php, html, json, twitter-typeahead

I am experimenting with twitter typeaheads [prefetch](http://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/examples/#prefetch) which fetches and processes data on initialization (json in my case).

My file structure is as follows;

```
- search.php
- title.json (created only when conn.php is visited)
- lib
- - conn.php
```

I am executing a simple query in my `lib/conn.php` file, this creates `title.json` containing all the relevant data. However I am only able to create this file by visiting the `conn.php` page manually in my browser.

How can I 'run' `conn.php` when a user visits the `search.php` page (hence creating the title.json)?

I have tried to add `<?php include('lib/conn.php') ?>` and `<?php require_once('lib/conn.php') ?>` to the top of my `search.php` but it doesn't seem to work.

The `title.json` is never created, with the console throwing a 404 not found for the `title.json` file. However whenever I manually type `mydomain/lib/conn.php` the file is created and all works well on the next visit to my search page.

Perhaps I am not implementing this the most efficient way, if so any advice is appreciated as I am trying to teach myself here!

I have included my code for reference;

**lib/conn.php**

```
<?php

$db = new mysqli('localhost', 'MyDbUser', 'MyDbPass', 'MyDbName');

$sql = ("SELECT title FROM publication");

$data = array();

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
    $data[] = $row['title'];
}

file_put_contents('../title.json', json_encode($data));

?>
```

**search.php**

```
<?php include('lib/conn.php') ?>

<body>
<div class="container">       
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12" id="prefetch">
            <input class="typeahead form-control" type="text" placeholder="search here...">
        </div>
    </div>
</div> 
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is relative paths. In php the starting script defines the include dir. Your conn.php tries to save in the folder above the search.php file. If you define your root dir as a constant you can use that constant in all scripts. Some popular CMS defines the root dir, the lib dir, the module dir, etc.

Try this in search.php

```
<?php define("MyRoot", __DIR__); include(MyRoot . '/lib/conn.php'); ?>
```

And in conn.php

```
<?php file_put_contents(MyRoot . '/title.json', json_encode($data)); ?>
```

You might also want to config your webserver so that json files are the correct mime type and cacheable for x minutes.

Comment: This works perfectly @OIS - can you briefly explain where I was going wrong? Or what your answer does. Thanks again

Comment: @johnny_s added brief explanation :)